# References to self-created environments in latex

Tags: latex, reference, label

How is possible to define labels and corresponding references to a self-defined environment within latex?

Example:

```
\newcounter{fpcounter}
\newenvironment{fp}[2]
{
\stepcounter{fpcounter}
\label{#1}
\textbf{Problem~\arabic{fpcounter}}
}
{}
```

Any references to the included label though get redirected to the surrounding section/subsection/paragraph though.

Any hints?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd recommend [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) for any future questions related to LaTeX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`. This sets what the `\label` command will use, and redefine `thefpcounter` with `\renewcommand{\thefpcounter}{\arabic{fpcounter}}`. This yields

[image]

Also, have provided some other options depending on how you want to label the custom environment.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcounter{fpcounter}
%\renewcommand{\thefpcounter}{\thechapter.\arabic{fpcounter}}
%\renewcommand{\thefpcounter}{\thesection.\arabic{fpcounter}}
\renewcommand{\thefpcounter}{\arabic{fpcounter}}

\newenvironment{fp}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{fpcounter}%
\label{#1}%
\noindent\textbf{Problem~\thefpcounter}%
}%
{}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
\section{Ipsum}

\begin{fp}{fp:A}{}
content of environment 1
\end{fp}

\begin{fp}{fp:B}{}
content of environment 2
\end{fp}

\medskip\noindent
As shown in Problem~\ref{fp:A}, and Problem~\ref{fp:B}...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted my custom environment to be numbered in sequence with equations, so I simply used `\refstepcounter{equation}` without defining any new counters.

Comment: @GavinR.Putland: Glad my answer was able to help. However, I'd recommend [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) for any future LaTeX inquiries.